# Equivalence between two definitions of Complex Tangent Space

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-spaces, almost-complex

I have two definitions of "Complex Tangent Space" over a Complex Manifold $M$ of (complex) dimension $n$. One of them is defining, over the real tangent space $T_p(M)$, the complex structure $J_p :T_p(M) \rightarrow T_p(M)$ given by
$$J_p \left(\frac {\partial}{\partial x_i}|_p \right) = \frac {\partial}{\partial y_i}|_p \quad ; \quad J_p \left(\frac {\partial}{\partial y_i}|_p \right) = -\frac {\partial}{\partial x_i}|_p$$
Where $\{ \partial/\partial x_i |_p, \partial/\partial y_i|_p\}_{i=1,...,n}$ is a (real) basis in $T_p(M)$ induced by a complex chart. It's easy to show that this, indeed, is a complex structure and does not depend on the choise of complex chart. This way, the tangent space is now a complex vector space of dimension $n$ and we can think of the "Complex Tangent Bundle" as a complex vector bundle over $M$ with fiber $T_p(M)$ (seen as a complex vector space) at each $p \in M$.

Another way to define the complex tangent space is by doing a "mimic" with the definition of the real tangent space. We define $H_p(M)$ as the space of pairs $(f,U)$, beeing $U \subseteq M$ open with $p \in U$ and $f :U \rightarrow \Bbb C$ holomorphic, quotient by the equivalence relation
$$(f,U) \sim (g,V)  \iff  \exists \ W \subseteq U \cap V \ \ \mathrm{open} \ \mathrm{with} \ \ p\in W \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ f|_W =g|_W$$
We define the holomorphic tangent space at $p\in M$ as the set of $\Bbb C$-linear functions $X_p :H_p(M) \rightarrow \Bbb C$ that satisfy the Leibniz Rule (we will write this space as $T_p^h (M)$). It can be shown that this is a complex vector space of dimension $n$. We will name "Holomorphic Tangent Bundle" the complex vector bundle over $M$ with fiber $T_p^h(M)$ at each $p \in M$. If $f : M \rightarrow N$ is an holomorphic function between complex manifolds, and $p \in M$, we define $\hat d f_p :T_p^h(M) \rightarrow T_p^h(N)$ by
$$\hat d f_p (X_p) ([h]) := X_p(h \ \mathrm{o} \ f)$$

So, we defined the "Complex Tangent Bundle" $T(M)$ and the "Holomorphic Tangent Bundle" $T^h(M)$. My question is

- Can we find, for each complex manifold $M$, a natural isomorphism of complex vector bundles $F^M : T(M) \rightarrow T^h(M)$ such that, if $F_p^M :T_p(M) \rightarrow T_p^h(M)$ is the induced $\Bbb C$-linear isomorphism for each $p \in M$, then $\hat d f_p \ \mathrm{o} \ F_p^M = F_{f(p)}^N \ \mathrm{o} \ df_p$ for every holomorphic function $f : M \rightarrow N $ ? (I don't know how to draw conmutative diagrams)

If we can accomplish this, then I will be convinced that this two definitions are "Equivalent".

Comment: Is it holomorphic instead?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I thought it is called "holomorphic tangent space" instead of holomorfic tangent space?

Comment: Oh, yes, my native language is spanish and "ph" sounds like "f"

Comment: In [Holomorphic tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_tangent_bundle) Your question belongs to the section alternative local description. It uses some different symbols though. The definition with p is strong dependent on each p  and p=M. Therefore this condition is stronger for p smaller than M but equivalent to the case M for all p. If not this fails. This failure is to be shown as counterexample. Every nonholomorphic component function will do. If holomorphic its okay. [Tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) has Leibniz.

Comment: I didn't get the "The definition with p is strong dependent on each p and p=M"...who is p? The wikipedia links didn't seem useful, it never mentions my second definition of "complex tangent space". It does, tho, talk about the transition maps which might be key in what I'm asking (or not)